# Packer vs VM on Azure: Timeout waiting for WinRM

Tags: packer, winrm, azure-vm

I'm using Packer to build VM images on Azure for a while, but today it stopped working without any changes from my side (Packer version is still 1.5.1 and template wasn't changed)

I'm getting **Timeout waiting for WinRM** error

I've checked:
1. Packer build on Azure DevOps and local machine;
2. `2016-Datacenter` and `2019-Datacenter` images;
3. Different versions of image (e.g. `17763.914.1912042330` and `17763.973.2001110547` for `2019-Datacenter`);
4. "West Europe" and "East US" regions;
5. Different VM sizes as per this [comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/8658);
6. Packer build in auto-created and pre-defined resource groups.

Port 5986 is available for telnet.

Anybody is facing the same?

**UPD**: this was met before yesterday, but ~ 1 failure per 10 builds, yesterday it was ~ 9 failures per 10 builds

**UPD2**: I'му get rid of Packer and replaced it with Azure CLI: https://github.com/kagarlickij/azure-packer-alternative

Answer (score 0):

Not only does this happen on Windows VM's but I also face the same issue on Linux ones using SSH. I have to press re-run all the time, then it magically works.  So you see the issue is that SSH/WinRM simply wasn't ready to receive a connection from packer at the time it tried.  Probably the cloud provider took to long to spin up the base VM.

So the issue can be fixed by Packer simply adding a single retry function for timed out connections, but they haven't. It doesn't seem like it's on their todo list either. So there's no fix I'm aware of unless you wanted to code an until loop or something like that yourself.